# Why won't this code recognise that these two variables are the same?

Tags: java, compare

Hey I'm trying to take a String input from the user (in this case a name of a film e.g. Good Burger).  I have an arraylist of class Film from which I'm iterating through.  On each iteration a method in the instance of class Film is called which returns a String of the film name.  When I'm comparing these two, it doesn't seem to recognise that they are equal and I can't figure out why.

Heres the code that's taking the input and comparing the two:

//Get the films input by the user.

```
    int numberOfFilmsCheck;
    numberOfFilmsCheck = 0;
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Film tempFilm;
    System.out.println("Please enter the names of the films you wish to be in the new schedule");
    System.out.println("Press enter after each one.");

    while(numberOfFilmsCheck < numberOfFilms){
        boolean foundFilm;
        foundFilm = false;
        String inputFilmName = null;
        tempFilm = null;
        String filmName;
        filmName = null;
        try{
            inputFilmName = reader.readLine();
            System.out.println(inputFilmName);
        }
        catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        for(Film film : films){
            film.printFilmName();
            if(inputFilmName.equals(filmName)){
                foundFilm = true;
                tempFilm = film;
                System.out.println("Found film name");
                break;
            }
        }

        if(foundFilm == true){
            newFilmsForSchedule.add(tempFilm);
            numberOfFilmsCheck++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The film you entered has not been recognised.");
            System.out.println("Please enter the film name as shown above.");
        }
```

and here is the code in class Film that returns the film name:

```
public String getFilmName()
{
    return filmName;
}
```

If you notice any rogue print statements in there that's just me checking the code is working correctly.

Any help is much appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Check the case of the film names, and make sure all spacing (before, within, after) is identical. Show us your input data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, all case and spacing is identical.  I'm creating a film that takes parameters name, id and length.  For example:  film4 = new Film("The Death Stroke", 4, 1.5);
        film5 = new Film("Cool Runnings", 5, 2);

Comment: @Omar - I assume this is the line that is failing? _if(inputFilmName.equals(filmName)){_  Before that line, print out filmname, too.

Comment: All case and spacing of the input is identical to the film name.  I'm creating a film that takes parameters name, id and length. For example: film4 = new Film("The Death Stroke", 4, 1.5); film5 = new Film("Cool Runnings", 5, 2).

Comment: Ah yes, that's the one that's failing.  Sorry I didn't make it clear :)  Yeah I was just printing it out to see if the code actually got that far haha

Comment: Use .compareTo() when comparing strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getFilmName()` function looks like quite a useful one, but only if you end up calling it :-)

You appear to set `filmName` to null at the start, then you never actually *change* it (by calling `getFilmName()`, for example). Hence, it will be null for the purposes of comparison.

I suspect you may need something like:

```
for(Film film : films){
    film.printFilmName();
    filmName = film.getFilmName();               // <-- Added this.
    if(inputFilmName.equals(filmName)){          // <-- So that this works.
        foundFilm = true;
        tempFilm = film;
        System.out.println("Found film name");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It was bound to be something as simple as that! haha, silly me, thank you for all your responses, they're greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this code:

```
System.out.println("'" + inputFilmName + "' vs '" + filmName + "'")
```

before the `if(inputFilmName.equals(filmName)){` line and you WILL see why it is not equal. Oh notice the single quotes..